# How to make a progressbar and in the label it describe its related percentage with 2 decimal points?

Tags: c#

I am creating an c# application.
I put one progressbar, one label and one timer control on the form.

I want that when my form loads, the progressbar loads and in the label its related percentage displays.

timer1 controls property set in property window as below :

```
Enabled = true
Interval = 100
```

**Code:**

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) <br>
{ 
   this.progressBar1.Increment(1);  
}
```

Lots of Thanks for help..

I also have two problems

[1]How to display progress in percentage format 
    like : 86.99....

[2]How to open second form when 100.00% completed ?

Answer (score 1):

So just add this code into your `timer1_Tick` event and display value in the label, like "1.00, 2.00 ..":

```
label1.Text = String.Format("{0}", progressBar1.Value.ToString("F2"));
```

For more information about `Numeric Format Strings` take a look at here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Or define a double variable:

```
double myProgress = 0.0;
```

Set your timer1 Interval to 100

```
timer1.Interval = 100; // you could write this on form load
```

And in Timer_Tick:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myProgress += 0.05;
        label1.Text = String.Format("{0} %", myProgress.ToString("F2"));
        if(Math.Abs(myProgress % 2.00) < 0.1) progressBar1.Increment(1);
        if ((int) myProgress >= 100)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
            timer1.Stop();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Lots of Thanks for help..

I have two problems

[1]How to display progress in percentage format 
 like : 86.99.... 
[2]How to open second form when 100.00% completed ?

Comment: also don't forget to stop timer

Comment: Thanks. <br/> But how to display process in the format like 95.65%

Comment: Progressbar value is integer,you can't do it with progress bar value but you can do some math.

Comment: I understood what you are telling me. If you know how to possible this with mathematical way so please give me the code.

Comment: How about now, @argciv ?

Comment: I understood what you are telling me. If you know how to possible this with mathematical way so please give me the code.

Comment: Lots of thanks.. I checked your answer but this code works in slow process.

Answer (score 0):

Add a secound `Timer: timer2;` `enabled = true`; `interval = 1;`

```
double progress = 0d;
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    progress += 0.01d; //Increment of progress
    label1.Text = progress.ToString(); // Converts progress to string
    this.Update(); // Redraws form. Needed because timer is too fast for 60fps.
}
```

Comment: Lots of Thanks for help..

I also have one problems

[1]How to display progress in percentage format like : 86.99....